# Blank line in balloon

Tags: manga, orthography, typesetting

While reading manga, I noticed sometimes in a balloon there is an extra empty line, like here:

[image]

Which meaning does it carry? I'm wondering if it's meant to separate the two sentences, like saying that たった一輪の「華」なのだよ is separate from, not modified by, the previous sentence; but I'm not sure, and the comma after 「添えられた」 adds to the confusion.

Comment: Is it different size fonts right and left of the empty line?

Comment: It is, on the left is bigger, good catch; not sure what that means either.

Comment: Probably an emphasis, but I have no idea to explain. So, I added the tags to get it noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manga typesetting is a science in itself, but in this instance I think there is no "empty line", it is just some extra space that visually separates the part in the larger font (larger for emphasis / louder voice) from the rest of the sentence.

In general such white space might also indicate a brief pause.

Comment: So 添えられた is to be read as modifying たった一輪, like "It's just one flower that accompanies"?